# Android webview - keep alive in background and create notification on page update?

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a webview that I would like to keep alive in the background.  Basically, I want to detect page updates to that webview, and display a notification when this occurs.

Is this possible at all?  I don't recall any attributes for webview keep-alive, and how would I detect a webview change?  Would a service be involved?  I'm very confused as to how I'd implement such an idea.

By the way, my entire application is set up and it works, I just need to now keep the webview alive.

Answer (score 0):

`keep alive **in the background**`

are you going to send a notification while the app is not showing on the screen?
if so, please take a look at the:  [google gcm](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: Yes.  This is the problem I am experiencing:  I don't own the server.  This app is simply nothing more than a webview that opens a webmail page.  (it's to keep customers happy)

Comment: can you tell how is the website being updated? by other server or programmatically ?

Comment: The server.  It's Gmail.  It's a corporate Google Apps account, so we can't sign in with Android's Email or Gmail clients, as it's managed by the organization.

Comment: if i am not mistaken, the user will login gmail in the webview, and if there is a new email, the app will inform the user, right?

Comment: Yes, it will.  But I want it to notify them even if the application is not in the foreground.

Comment: Please take a look at the second answer of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434889/in-android-app-can-i-listen-for-emails-that-arrive-in-gmail

Comment: I can't connect using SMTP, POP, IMAP, etc etc.  The gapps account is managed by an external (non-Google) company, and they've disabled SMTP/POP/IMAP access.  We are forced to use Webmail in all cases.

Comment: in java, make a httprequest to that server to get the html, check if there is new email by analyzing the html element. Then repeat the request every minute/ 30seconds in `android background service`.

Comment: can you find your answer here? if you do so, would you mind accepting the answer?