# Can I detect if I received an email from gmail?

Tags: android

It is possible to detect if I receive an email from gmail in my device catching an intent for example with a receiver ?

I try this but it seem not working :

```
contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls"), true, gmailObserver);
```

Comment: Do you only want to "detect" the arrival of the e-mail, or do you want to read the whole e-mail?

Comment: Just detect the arrival of the email

Comment: Did you try NotificationListenerService? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499588/detect-incoming-email-notification-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Android app can I listen for emails that arrive in GMAIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434889/in-android-app-can-i-listen-for-emails-that-arrive-in-gmail)